# how to get rid of the non alphabetic character at the end of the word using python nltk

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to extract nouns from text using python nltk package. It more or less worked. But I wonder how to get rid of the non-alphabetic character at the end of words? Please see the following example.

```
from nltk.tag import pos_tag                     
x = "Back, Back: Back"                           
tagged_sent = pos_tag(x.split())
y = [word for word,pos in tagged_sent if pos == 'NNP']
```

Then y takes value

```
['Back,', 'Back:', 'Back']
```

What I really want is

```
['Back', 'Back', 'Back']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
re.findall(r'\w+', x)
```

instead of

```
x.split()
```

(This will give you alphanumeric blocks; if you really want just alphabetic, `[a-zA-Z]` should be a good start, but that won't deal well with non-English characters even if you specify `re.UNICODE`; `\w` does.)

Answer (score 0):

Using filter:

```
>>> my_str = "Back, Back: Back"
>>> [filter(str.isalnum, x) for x in my_str.split()]
['Back', 'Back', 'Back']
```

Using itertools.takewhile

```
>>> my_str = "Back, Back: Back"
>>> ["".join(x) for x in map(lambda x:list(itertools.takewhile(str.isalnum, x)), my_str.split())]
['Back', 'Back', 'Back']
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use [re.sub()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=re.sub#re.sub). Change your last line of code to

```
import re
y = [re.sub('[^A-Za-z]+$', '', word) for word,pos in tagged_sent if pos == 'NNP']
```